# If $z_{n} \rightarrow z$ then $|z_{n}|\leq M$ for all n.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_{n}$ be a sequence of complex numbers.  Prove that If $z_{n} \rightarrow z$, then there exists $M>0$ such that $|z_{n}|\leq M$ for all n.

Proof:  Since $z_{n} \rightarrow z$, then for each $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $n_{0}$, so that if $n>n_{0}$, then

$|z_{n}| = |z+ (z_{n} - z)| \leq |z| + |z_{n}-z| < |z| + \varepsilon$.

I don't know how to complete this proof for *all $n$*.

Comment: Let $M=\max\{|z|+\varepsilon, |z_1|, \dots, |z_{n_0}|\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $M=\max\{|z|+\varepsilon, |z_1|, \dots, |z_{n_0}|\}<\infty$. Then we have $|z_n|\le M$ for *all* $n$.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the important part.

For the rest:
Notice that there's only finitely many $z_n$ with $n\leq n_0$, and select
$$
M=\max\left\{|z|+\varepsilon,|z_1|,|z_2|,\ldots,|z_{n_0}|\right\}
$$

Answer (score 2):

You are almost done, you can conclude the claim by stating
$|z_n|\leq \max(|z|+\varepsilon,|z_1|,|z_2|,|z_3|,...,|z_{n_0}|)$.